# Reuse angular directives within other directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to lazy load images and iframes (i.e. set the src once the element is in the viewport). I have an existing angular directive `is-visible` that sets the `is-visible` attribute when an element scrolls into view. How do I reuse this directive from within my `set-src-when-visible` directive?

i.e., I want this code to reuse the `is-visible` directive:

```
<img set-src-when-visible="http://example.com/img.png" />`
<iframe set-src-when-visible="http://example.com/" />
```

---

#### Unsatisfactory approach 1: Require `is-visible` directive

I can require the `is-visible` directive to be on the same element I am declaring the `set-src-when-visible` directive on:

```
<img set-src-when-visible="url" is-visible />

myApp.directive('setSrcWhenVisible', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'isVisible',
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            var set = false;
            attrs.$observe('isVisible', function(isVisible) {
                if(isVisible && !set) {
                    attrs.$set('src', $scope.$eval(attrs.setSrcWhenVisible));
                    set = true;
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/pvtpenguin/6tCk6/

**Downside:** I'd like to be able to specify only the `set-src-when-visible` directive while still reusing `is-visible`.

---

#### Unsatisfactory approach 2:

Create two directives, one for iframe and one for img tag:

```
<iframe set-iframe-src-when-visible="url"></iframe>
<img set-img-src-when-visible="url" />

angular.forEach(['Iframe', 'Img'], function(tagName) {
    var directiveName = 'set' + tagName + 'SrcWhenVisible';
    myApp.directive(directiveName, function ($window) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            template: '<' + tagName + ' is-visible></' + tagName + '>',
            replace: true,
            link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
                var set = false;
                attrs.$observe('isVisible', function(value) {
                    if(value && !set) {
                        attrs.$set('src', $scope.$eval(attrs[directiveName]));
                        set = true;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/pvtpenguin/K4JuC/2/

**Downside**: different names for each directive, plus this doesn't fit well with the method I am using to declare and configure my app.

Comment: My understanding is that `require` is used to require another controller, so you probably don't need to specify that attribute in your `setSrcWhenVisible` directive definition object.  If you don't want to copy the `isVisible` code (that sets an attribute when an element scrolls into view) into the `setSrcWhenVisible` directive, then I don't think you have any other choice but to add the `is-visible` attribute to the element... otherwise how would the element get this functionality?

Comment: Thanks, @Mark. One way would be to use a template that includes the is-visible directive, [like this working example](http://jsfiddle.net/pvtpenguin/8nJtW/2/), but that will only work with a single tag type per directive, so I would have to make two directives, one for an `img` tag and one for an `iframe`

Comment: Also, @mark, 'require' enforces that `is-visible` is present on the same element as `set-src-when-visible`.

Comment: Thanks for the info regarding `require`.  (I personally wouldn't use it that way though, since other coders would probably assume that the `setSrcWhenVisible` directive is going to use the `isVisible` controller.)  You should be able to add a compile function to your example fiddle and dynamically determine which tag type to use.  I like that approach best so far.

Comment: @mark, I'm struggling to figure out how to do this. I can't change the tagname of the template without creating a whole new one, and I can't add the is-visible attribute in the compile function because that is after angular has determined which directives to compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our comment discussion, here is a link function that hopefully will do what you want:

```
link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
   $scope.src = attrs.setSrcWhenVisible;  // save attribute -- is $eval needed?
   var tagName = element[0].tagName;
   if(tagName == 'IMG') {
      var jqLiteWrappedElement = angular.element('<img is-visible></img>');
   } else {
      var jqLiteWrappedElement = angular.element('<iframe is-visible></iframe>');
   }
   element.replaceWith(jqLiteWrappedElement);
   $compile(jqLiteWrappedElement)($scope);
   var set = false;
   attrs.$observe('isVisible', function(value) {
      if(value && !set) {
         attrs.$set('src', $scope.src);
         set = true;
      }
   });
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/BD26R/)